# React complex filter with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

UPDATED QUESTION.

I am trying to introduce a filter to my map so users can define which options they want to see with multiple selection boxes.

The problem I am facing is actually the page after they have filtered the options.

Example: I have 5 names all with different colours and with different active statuses stored in a array like so:

```
const info = [
{ name: "A1"
  colour: "Blue"
  active: "Yes"
},
{ name: "B2"
  colour: "Red"
  active: "Yes"
},
{ name: "C3"
  colour: "Green"
  active: "No"
},
{ name: "D4"
  colour: "Yellow"
  active: "No"
},
{ name: "E5"
  colour: "Orange"
  active: "Yes"
},
```

I filter the "non active" using

```
{info.filter(info => info.active.includes("Yes")).map((index, value) => {
return (
   <div>{info[value].name}</div>
   //THIS DOES NOT DISPLAY THE CORRECT NAME FOR A START.
   <Navlink to={{ pathname: "/confirmChoices", state: {choice: value}}>CLICK</Navlink>
   //THIS IS NOW PASSING THE WRONG VALUE TO THE NEXT PAGE.
)};
```

The page displays the correct amount of items so:

```
A1
CLICK
B2
CLICK
C3 // THIS SHOULD BE E5 
CLICK
```

Now the second problem is when I want to click on **C3** that should be **E5**. The next page loads and it displays the info for **C3** and not **E5**.

Like so

```
Name: C3
COLOUR: RED
ACTIVE: NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't making use of the variable in the callback inside `.map()`. That will point you to the correct value.

`.filter()` and `.map()` do not alter the original array and instead return a new array.

Since you are passing in the index value **from the original array** as a prop, you cannot use index inside your `.map()`. This index(in this case 2) is not the index of **E5**. You will have to get the index from the original array using something like `findIndex`.

```
{info.filter(info => info.active.includes("Yes")).map((value, index) => {
let originalIndex = info.findIndex((item)=>item.name == value.name);
return (
   <div>{value.name}</div>
   <Navlink to={{ pathname: "/confirmChoices", state: {choice: originalIndex }}>CLICK</Navlink>
)};
```

Also will suggest using better variable names. The first param in `.map()` callback is the value, and second is the index.

Comment: That fixes it on the current page however once I go to the second page I am still getting "C3" and not "E5". I use `const value = this.props.location.state.choice` on the second page to get the value

Comment: Edited my answer. Looks like you are using the index and original array in the next page.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much saved me a headache. Do you mind explaining why you pass in `item` and not just use `name == value.name`?

Comment: Because inside your callback item points to the array element which is an object with a property `name`. This is not just an array of names. Does that help?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Is it possible to have `info.selectableOption.includes...` instead of `info.active.includes...` so basically a dynamic filter depending on which one has been clicked by a user?

Comment: For that it is `info[selectableOption].includes` . this is called ComputedPropertyName

Comment: Last question.. How would I set `selectableOption` from an onclick? Because its not a state so would it still update? If i define it saying var selectableOption = "active". Do i just add a new var selectable option inside my onclick?

Comment: Never mind I was being an idiot. I figured it out :) Thanks for all your help, would upvote more if i could xD